# How do you write a linux shell script to manipulate filenames and create new file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have not done a lot of shell scripting, but I am a High School CS teacher and I am looking to take a directory of students work and rename each file accordingly, as well as create a new file for feedback.  For example, after downloading submissions I have a directory of files that look like this:

`studentname_1234_4567_desiredFileName.java`   -or-
`studentname_LATE_1234_5678_desiredFileName.java`  -or- `studentname_1234_5678_desiredFileName-1.java` and other potential combinations of these.

My goal is to get the script to extract    `desiredFileName.java` and rename the file, as well as extract studentname to pass to my grading script.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# this should be whatever folder your submissions are in
cd programs || exit
for filename in *; do
    # strip away everything before the last underscore
    desired_filename=${filename##*_}
    # strip away the file extension
    desired_filename=${desired_filename%.*}
    # strip everything after a dash and add .java file extension back
    desired_filename="${desired_filename%-*}.java"
    # strip away everything after the first underscore
    studentname=${filename%%_*}
    # rename the file
    mv "$filename" "$desired_filename"
    # or however you want to invoke your script
    echo "$studentname submitted file $desired_filename"
done
```

File structure before running:

```
script.sh
programs/
  | alice_LATE_1234_5678_alicesfile.java
  | bob_LATE_1234_5678_bobsfile-1.java
  | jane_1234_5678_janesfile.java
```

Output:

```
alice submitted file alicesfile.java
bob submitted file bobsfile.java
jane submitted file janesfile.java
```

File structure after running:

```
script.sh
programs/
  | alicesfile.java
  | bobsfile.java
  | janesfile.java
```

([read here](https://devhints.io/bash) for more info on the string manipulation syntax used in the script)

Comment: worked perfectly, thank you.  I appreciate the link as well.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you! When you have a question answered, you should [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so people know that the question is answered.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I took care of it